# how to perform action(listener) from the function?

Tags: android

I use the following code to return the Scroll View from the function.That Scroll View contain number of check boxes . I call this function and it return the Scroll View correctly.But how to get the value if any of the check box is checked i need to perform some action.How to do this ?

Scroll View return Function:

```
 public ScrollView MyViewGroup(String[] Fields,int width,int height)throws Exception{   

    ScrollView sc=new ScrollView(context);
    sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,
            height));

    TableLayout tbl=new TableLayout(context);       

    for(int i=0;i<Fields.length;i++){       
        TableRow tr=new TableRow(context);          
        CheckBox ch=new CheckBox(context);
        ch.setId(i);
        ch.setText(Fields[i]);
        tr.addView(ch);
        tbl.addView(tr);            
    }

    sc.addView(tbl);
    return sc;      
}
```

and i use this function like the following way

```
  LinearLay.addView(MyGui.MyViewGroup(strarr[],200,200);
```

Note :

MyGui class i create TextViews,EditTexts,Buttons and ScrollView .By using this MyGui Class i create the GUI 's only.I have one activity myform .In that myform class when i click the submit button i need get the checked value's and get some other Edittext Values from the user and take action for the submit Button only.Is there any possibility to do this ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `Context` of the UI elements as parameter to the method, and subscribe checkboxes to the `OnClickListener` event

so it would be something like

```
class clsLinearLay implements Button.OnClickListener {
....
// implement the method
}



LinearLay.addView(MyGui.MyViewGroup(this,strarr[],200,200);

public ScrollView MyViewGroup(Context ctx, String[] Fields,int width,int height)

CheckBox ch=new CheckBox(ctx);
ch.setOnClickListener(ctx); // this will fire in the context class when the state is changed
```

Comment: I already set the context for the class MyGui.In this MyGui class i create TextViews,EditTexts,Buttons and ScrollView also;By using this MyGui Class i create the GUI 's only.I have one activity myform .In that myform class when i click the submit button i need get the checked value's and get some other Edittext Values from the user and take action for the submit Button only